# How to save my "website" from collapsing when I zoom out my browser?

Tags: html, css

I am new to using div elements. The problem is the one that I have stated in the title of this topic. This is my code, I have looked through some topics that have been created on stackoverflow but I haven't found a nice solution to this problem. This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwt3V/

My HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Main</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="smth.php">Something</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">A LOT OF TEXT</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
body{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
}

.container{
    background-color: #160b9c;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
}

.navigation{
    float: left;
    width: 307px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.navigation ul{

}

.navigation li{
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.navigation li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.content{
    float: right;
    width: 715px;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain better with what you mean when you say "zoom out your browser" and what browser?

Comment: When I use CTRL and - or my mouse's scroll to zoom out. Firefox/Chrome/IE

Comment: I can't be more descriptive. This is my problem.
When I zoom out with my mouse scroll for example, my div design collapses. As you can see, when you zoom out the "A LOT OF TEXT" text goes under my navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I do not see the problem in Safari, which is actually a good thing. I can show you a better method to hold everything in one line and that is this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwt3V/3/). Let's break it down a little bit more though. If we are looking at this specific CSS element:

```
.container {
    background-color: #160b9c;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
}
```

We come to notice that it is not holding the divs inside of it in any special order or way. So that is why we restructure and add a display element:

```
.container {
    background-color: #160b9c;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And that should fix your problem. However, if this continues to not work for you, your question has been asked before and it's actually located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488114/website-layout-breaks-apart-when-zooming-in-or-out-in-browsers-a-few-other-b) and the top answer did a magnificent job explaining a few things.

Another thing I would like to leave you with is the [Almanac](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/). This can help you with any problem or hopefully any problem that you are having with CSS. And I would also suggest making sure everything is... current. So in other words, try to find the best screen size and this [website](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/best-screen-size/) can help you to find that.

Overall, good luck on your future coding, you got this :)

Comment: Thank you! You answer was the most descriptive and the most helpful.

Comment: Anytime :)  Good luck with it all :)

Answer (score 1):

take all your widths in % and decrease width of `.content` here is the fiddle for your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/QdDLn/

Answer (score 0):

don't float your .content div to the right.

```
.content{
    width: 715px;
}
```