# Making webpage look good on zoom out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Link A)
needreceipt.com/receiptGenerator6/public/home

Link B)
expressexpense.com

Website on Link B seem to stay in one container on zoom out and hence looks clean.Website on Link A does not seem to stay in one container on zoom out and hence does not look clean.
How can i solve this issue?

**SOLUTION TRIED**
I put everything in one large container but that created unnecessary margins.
I put everything in one large container and set margin to 0% and width to 100%.This took me back to how the site worked originally.

Comment: for the `css` on the `#exampleTemplates` change `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
 #exampleTemplates { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}` and it would already look better, thing is the of margins is breaking it with the @media queries especially.

Comment: also have a look at his to help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488114/website-layout-breaks-apart-when-zooming-in-or-out-in-browsers-a-few-other-b/11494834

Answer (score 0):

First of all add class with id="exampleTemplates".

```
<div class="container" id="exampleTemplates">
```

secondly do this. Then your layout remain same zoom Out or zoom In.

```
.parent{ widht: 30%; margin-left: 0%;}
```